Option to Log Exceptions Only on Final Retry When Using FilamentExceptions
I am using Laravel 11 with Filament v3 together with bezhanSalleh/filament-exceptions to manage and log exceptions in my application. My notifications and some other Jobs are dispatched using a Redis queue, with retries configured (up to 3 or sometimes 5 attempts).
Currently, FilamentExceptions logs every exception, even for intermediate retries. This results in duplicate log entries for the same error when the job is retried. For example, if a notification fails due to a network issue (Connection to "xxx" has been closed unexpectedly) but succeeds on the second or third retry, the initial errors are still logged to filament exceptions.
Also, very important! Some jobs do not have a set retry variable. If those jobs fail on the first try, this means this is also the last try. Of course, I also want to log those failures. I only want to get rid of failed jobs being logged, which still have another retry left. Intermediate retry failures should not be logged to avoid noise in the logs. How can I archive this?
The "problem" is that bezhanSalleh/filament-exceptions registers globally within the app.php:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            'webhooks/*',
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            FilamentExceptions::report($e);
        });
    })->create();


